# Outlook 365, hide condensed month calendar in To-Do-Bar, but leave appointment details

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, sidebar

while it is possible to show more than one month in the side pane in outlook (by dragging the separator line), I couldn't find any way hide that view at all **without losing appointment details**

How this calendar view can be hidden, but leave the appointment details visible?

[image]

Comment: While it is possible to derive a question from what you have written, you didn't include an actual question. Please edit and add a question.

Answer (score 0):

> How this calendar view can be hidden, but leave the appointment details visible?

This is not possible. [A similar question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/modify-docked-calendar-peek/093628dd-6a1f-47a5-85ef-23a9105488c0#:%7E:text=No%2C%20sorry%2C%20it%27s%20not%20possible%20to%20remove%20the%20mini%20calendar%20from%20the%20peek.) has been asked years ago in MS Answers Community but the answer is still the same, that is, not feasible now.

You can submit a feature request via the MS feedback portal for Outlook. That way it becomes an official request to Outlook Engineering and others can vote on the feature as well.
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/89a8afa3-2e1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472